# Azure data-factory can't load data successfully through PolyBase if the source data in the last column of the first row is null

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, polybase

I am try using Azure DataFactory to load data from Azure Blob Storage to Azure Data warehouse
The relevant data is like below:

source csv:

```
1,james,
2,john,usa
```

sink table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_null (
    id int NOT NULL,
    name nvarchar(128)  NULL,
    address nvarchar(128)  NULL
)
```

source dataset:

```
{
    "name": "test_null_input",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "StagingBlobStorage",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
                "fileName": "1.csv",
                "folderPath": "test_null",
                "container": "adf"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "",
            "firstRowAsHeader": false,
            "quoteChar": ""
        },
        "schema": []
    }
}
```

sink dataset:

```
{
    "name": "test_null_output",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "StagingAzureSqlDW",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureSqlDWTable",
        "schema": [
            {
                "name": "id",
                "type": "int",
                "precision": 10
            },
            {
                "name": "name",
                "type": "nvarchar"
            },
            {
                "name": "address",
                "type": "nvarchar"
            }
        ],
        "typeProperties": {
            "schema": "dbo",
            "table": "test_null"
        }
    }
}
```

pipeline

```
{
    "name": "test_input",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "SqlDWSink",
                        "allowPolyBase": true,
                        "polyBaseSettings": {
                            "rejectValue": 0,
                            "rejectType": "value",
                            "useTypeDefault": false,
                            "treatEmptyAsNull": true
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "mappings": [
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "ordinal": 1
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "id"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "ordinal": 2
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "name"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "ordinal": 3
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "name": "address"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "test_null_input",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "test_null_output",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

The last column for the first row is null so when run the pipeline it pops out the below error:

```
ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidColumnMappingColumnNotFound,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Invalid column mapping provided to copy activity: '{"Prop_0":"id","Prop_1":"name","Prop_2":"address"}', Detailed message: Column 'Prop_2' defined in column mapping cannot be found in Source structure.. Check column mapping in table definition.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'
```

Tried set the treatEmptyAsNull to true, still the same error. Tried set skipLineCount to 1, it can work well, seems the last column null data in the first row affects the loading of the entire file. But the weirder thing is that it  can also work well by enable staging even without setting treatEmptyAsNull and skipLineCount. In my scenario, it is unnecessary to enable it, since it is originally from blob to data warehouse. It seems unreasonable to change from blob to blob and then from blob to data warehouse after enabling, and it will bring additional data movement charges after enabling. I don't know why setting treatEmptyAsNull doesn't work, and then why enabling staging can work，this seems to make no sense？

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above with your Pipeline JSON and got same error.

[image]

This error occurred because as per your JSON, this is your copy data mapping between source and sink.

[image]

As per the above mapping you should have `Prop_0`, `Prop_1` and `Prop_2` as headers.
Here, as you didn't check the **First Row as header** in your source file, it is taking `Prop_0`, `Prop_1` as headers. Since there is a null value in your first Row there is no `Prop_2` column and that is the reason it is giving the error for that column.

To resolve it, Give a proper header your file in csv like below.

[image]

Then check the First Row as header in the source dataset.
It will give the mapping like below when you import.

[image]

Now, it will Execute successfully as mine.

**Result:**

You can see that the empty value taken as `NULL` in target table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I also thought about adding header but there are too many source files and not under my control. I also tried with bulk insert with treatEmptyAsNull=true, it can also work well. I wonder if I can solve this problem through configuration still using PolyBase, and why enabling staging can work. Is there any special processing in the staging stage?

Comment: I think when enabling the header, it is adding the header `Prop_0` to `Prop_2` for the file and sink is taking that in the mapping which won't give any error as first is Row is header. This might be the reason for it.

Comment: It makes sense to enable header to work. I mean why enabling staging can work without adding header. Although I don't want to make it work through enable staging, it will cause extra costs. I am still looking to solve this problem through configuration without modifying the source file.

Comment: ' I mean why enabling staging can work without adding header' because it is adding the header for you. AFAIK, in your case without header in the file and also without adding the header ADF won't identify the third column as the first row contains null for it.

Comment: If so, does it means that ADF has a way to know that I actually have three columns, I think this is a bug of ADF since the first row of the source data has two delimiters although without header row.